# nrf24 bluetooth image transfer

Tags: arduino, imageprocessing, nrf24l01, bluetooth-low-energy

I'm trying to build "arducam-bluetooth-module-wireless-image-system" using an NRF24L01.
I wish to have a long range transfer of a single image from a remote location to my Android phone whenever it becomes within range (once per day).
I figure this should be possible because I can use a beacon like Stick n' Find to transmit temperature, so, why not an image.
Just not sure if the NRF24 is the right piece of hardware to achieve this.
(I'm stuck trying to get my Android to find the Arduino over bluetooth.)

Related - Is anyone interested it helping to prototype some projects to satisfy niche use-cases?

Answer (score 1):

The NRF24L01+ is not a Bluetooth device. The nRF24 series itself implements its own more-or-less proprietary (but well documented and fairly simple) 2.4GHz signaling protocol.

While they can sort of ["play at"](http://doc.lijun.li/misc-nrf24-ble.html) being BLE devices, this is because the Bluetooth Low Energy signalling protocol itself is actually fairly simple too (and different than say the "main" Bluetooth 4.0 protocol).

So in short, the nRF24 is *not* the right piece of hardware for easily pairing with mobile devices.

Nordic do sell a variety of actual [BLE transceiver](https://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/Bluetooth-Smart-Bluetooth-low-energy) chips, for example their nRF51 and nRF52 series, which may be more what you're looking for. I'm not sure whether they are or are not the most competitive option for BLE. IIRC, they also sell some combo transceivers that are capable of a wide variety of protocols in the 2.4GHz band.